# SMO: No model built yet

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, moa

I am able to create a model in MOA(Weka) for case 1 but not for "case 2" (same data set). Could anyone explain why?

**Case 1 (IBk/LWL):**

```
java -cp moa.jar:weka.jar -javaagent:sizeofag.jar moa.DoTask "LearnModel -l (meta.WEKAClassifier -l (weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk)) -s (ArffFileStream -f training_s2w.arff -c 1) -O model.moa"

java -cp moa.jar:weka.jar -javaagent:sizeofag.jar moa.DoTask "EvaluateModel -m file:model.moa -s (ArffFileStream -f test_s2w.arff -c 1) -o predicted.txt"
```

Above two commands creates a model and apply it on test data successfully.

**Case 2 (SMO/J48/NaiveBayes/BayesNet):**

```
java -cp moa.jar:weka.jar -javaagent:sizeofag.jar moa.DoTask "LearnModel -l (meta.WEKAClassifier -l (weka.classifiers.functions.SMO)) -s (ArffFileStream -f training_s2w.arff -c 1) -O model.moa"

java -cp moa.jar:weka.jar -javaagent:sizeofag.jar moa.DoTask "EvaluateModel -m file:model.moa -s (ArffFileStream -f test_s2w.arff -c 1) -o predicted.txt"
```

But these two commands gives **output** as:

```
 "Model description:
SMO: No model built yet"
```

(I checked through Weka CLI that both training and test data is Weka compatible.)

What could be the possible reason(s)?